# ListView PageScrollPhysics snapping based on children width / PageView with viewportFraction < 1 align left

Tags: flutter

I have a PageView/ListView with a `viewportFraction` of 0.8 to show a preview of the next slide. It looks something like this:

[image]

It seems like it is not possible to have the current slide aligned to the left, as shown below. Is that correct?

[image]

I found this solution. Using a horizontally scrolling ListView with `PageScrollPhysics()`, at first looked promising however, this way the page snapping is based on the screen width (?) and not on the ListView children, so the snapping is off by quite a bit.

Is there a way to have the page snapping based on the size of the children?

Answer (score 6):

My answer comes a bit late but it might help others looking for the same thing.
the PageScrollPhysics uses the screen width. You need to create your own ScrollPhysics that uses your item width to paginate.
here is an example:

```
ListView.builder(
    physics: PagingScrollPhysics(itemDimension: YOUR_ITEM_WIDTH),
    itemCount:items.length,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return YOUR_CHILD();
    }
)
```

And the new ScrollPhysics:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PagingScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  final double itemDimension;

  PagingScrollPhysics({required this.itemDimension, ScrollPhysics? parent}) : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  PagingScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return PagingScrollPhysics(itemDimension: itemDimension, parent: buildParent(ancestor));
  }

  double _getPage(ScrollMetrics position) {
    return position.pixels / itemDimension;
  }

  double _getPixels(double page) {
    return page * itemDimension;
  }

  double _getTargetPixels(ScrollMetrics position, Tolerance tolerance, double velocity) {
    double page = _getPage(position);
    if (velocity < -tolerance.velocity) {
      page -= 0.5;
    } else if (velocity > tolerance.velocity) {
      page += 0.5;
    }
    return _getPixels(page.roundToDouble());
  }

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    if ((velocity <= 0.0 && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) || (velocity >= 0.0 && position.pixels >= position.maxScrollExtent)) return super.createBallisticSimulation(position, velocity);
    final Tolerance tolerance = this.tolerance;
    final double target = _getTargetPixels(position, tolerance, velocity);
    if (target != position.pixels) return ScrollSpringSimulation(spring, position.pixels, target, velocity, tolerance: tolerance);
    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool get allowImplicitScrolling => false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code of Alaa Eddine Cherbib's answer in order to show smoothly scrolling for all elements when it is a fixed-size list. Now instead of passing item dimension, you should pass the item count and the view size (usually the screen width itself). The item dimension is not needed because it will be calculated internally.

Now always the items will be snaped at the beginning of the view and when scrolling to the last item it will do it smoothly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PagingScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const PagingScrollPhysics(
      {required this.itemCount, required this.viewSize, super.parent});

  final double viewSize;

  final int itemCount;

  @override
  PagingScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) => PagingScrollPhysics(
      itemCount: itemCount, viewSize: viewSize, parent: buildParent(ancestor));

  double _getPage(double current, double itemDimension) =>
      current / itemDimension;

  double _getTargetPixels(
      ScrollMetrics position, Tolerance tolerance, double velocity) {
    // plus view size because the max scroll extent is about where the screen
    //  starts not where the screen ends.
    final pixels = position.maxScrollExtent + viewSize;
    final itemDimension = pixels / itemCount;
    var page = _getPage(position.pixels, itemDimension);
    if (velocity < -tolerance.velocity)
      page -= 0.5;
    else if (velocity > tolerance.velocity) page += 0.5;
    final pageRound = page.round();
    final itemsPerPage = viewSize ~/ itemDimension;
    final showingLastItem = pageRound == itemCount - itemsPerPage;
    if (showingLastItem) return pixels - viewSize;

    return pageRound * itemDimension;
  }

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    if ((velocity <= 0.0 && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) ||
        (velocity >= 0.0 && position.pixels >= position.maxScrollExtent))
      return super.createBallisticSimulation(position, velocity);
    final Tolerance tolerance = this.tolerance;
    final double target = _getTargetPixels(position, tolerance, velocity);
    if (target != position.pixels)
      return ScrollSpringSimulation(spring, position.pixels, target, velocity,
          tolerance: tolerance);
    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool get allowImplicitScrolling => false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to create your own ScrollPhysics though. Just pass a PageController to the ListView where you've set the viewportFraction.

Here's a complete example where you can toggle between laying out items in horizontal or vertical axis.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final double _itemExtent = 100;
  final double _itemSpacing = 20;

  PageController? _scrollController;
  Axis _axis = Axis.vertical;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _evaluateScrollController({required BoxConstraints constraints}) {
    double viewExtent =
        _axis == Axis.vertical ? constraints.maxHeight : constraints.maxWidth;
    double fraction = (_itemExtent + _itemSpacing) / viewExtent;
    if (_scrollController?.viewportFraction != fraction) {
      _scrollController = PageController(viewportFraction: fraction);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('ListView with snapping'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() =>
            _axis = _axis == Axis.vertical ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        _evaluateScrollController(constraints: constraints);
        return ListView(
          scrollDirection: _axis,
          physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
          controller: _scrollController,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: _axis == Axis.vertical ? _itemSpacing : 0,
            left: _axis == Axis.horizontal ? _itemSpacing : 0,
          ),
          children: List.generate(
            15,
            (index) => Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: _axis == Axis.vertical ? _itemSpacing : 0,
                right: _axis == Axis.horizontal ? _itemSpacing : 0,
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: _axis == Axis.vertical ? _itemExtent : null,
                width: _axis == Axis.horizontal ? _itemExtent : null,
                child: _Tile(i: index),
              ),
            ),
          ).toList(),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class _Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  final int i;
  const _Tile({required this.i});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.yellow[800],
        border: Border.all(),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text('$i'),
    );
  }
}
```